# I cannot get animate.js to initiate

Tags: javascript, html, anime.js

I am fairly new to this, and am unable to figure out why the animation won't trigger. I linked the script source to anime.min.js, I can see it in the sources panel. I even tried to use the cdnjs, but that didn't work either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jlondono Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="bg-primary bluesquare" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Anime JS -->
  <script src="/script/anime.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  anime({
    targets: '.bluesquare',
    translatex: 250
  });
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
  anime({
    targets: '.bluesquare',
    translatex: 250
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jlondono.me/script/anime.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="bg-primary bluesquare" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: first thing I don't get is why is you bootstrap js cdn loaded after the dom?

Comment: Are you sure the path `/script/anime.min.js` is correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe the path is correct. When I check the source code, I can see the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after hours of watching Youtube and looking at forum, its turns out it was a couple of things.

1. The targets was incorrect (after I changed this, it still didn't work)
2. I didn't capitalize the "X" in translateX.....

OOF. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

A `.` is usually used to indicate a class selector.

```
        <div **class**="bluesquare" class="bg-primary" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: I looked this over a million times and I feel like an idiot lol. Thank you for catching that. Unfortunately, it still does not work after the correction.

Comment: Thank you for the assist. It was a combination of what you mentioned...and I didn't capitalize the X in translateX....

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jlondono Stylesheet -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="bg-primary bluesquare" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Anime JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>
  
  anime({
  targets: '.bluesquare',
  width: '100%', // -> from '28px' to '100%',
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add File After Bootstrap.js

```
 <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Anime JS -->
  <script src="/script/anime.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  anime({
    targets: '.bluesquare',
    translatex: 250
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and It still doesn't work. Thank you.